# Add and deploy new meteor packages

Tags: meteor, heroku

(1) I forked a working meteor application to my Desktop

(2) I installed two packages, which are working on the localhost

(3) The location of the package folder is $HOME/.meteor

(4) After the deployment on heroku the packages haven't been considered

Do I need to update something in the build process before I deploy to heroku?

meteor list: (i.e. ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 is not considered on heroku)

```
accounts-password            1.1.4  Password support for accounts
blaze-html-templates         1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI   with Meteor Blaze
check                        1.1.0  Check whether a value matches a pattern
ecmascript                   0.1.6* Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
es5-shim                     4.1.14  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  1.2.89  Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui with multi-language support.
iron:router                  1.0.12  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jquery                       1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
meteor-base                  1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience            1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                        1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
session                      1.1.1  Session variable
standard-minifiers           1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                      1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap               3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
```

---

I deploy to heroku through git: 
git push heroku master -, after creating an application with the heroku toolbelt ([described here](http://justmeteor.com/blog/deploy-to-production-on-heroku/))

I added the packages through: 
meteor add

---

Build-LOG:

```
-----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git... done

-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Installing node

-----> Installing meteor

Downloading Meteor distribution

Meteor 1.2.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).

Now you need to do one of the following:

(1) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or

(2) Run this command as root:

    cp "/tmp/buildpack20160301-158-vdh6o9/meteor-xBgh/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.10/mt-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-meteor" /usr/bin/meteor

Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at

docs.meteor.com.

-----> Bundling bundle

-----> Building Meteor with ROOT_URL: https://<appname>.herokuapp.com

npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important features,

npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the primary npm

npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at least npm@2, if not the

npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To upgrade to npm@2, run:

npm WARN deprecated 

npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest-2

npm WARN deprecated 

npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run:

npm WARN deprecated 

npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest

npm WARN deprecated 

npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you

npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if

npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)

npm WARN deprecated 

npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with

npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS

npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small

npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and

npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.

npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description

npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.

npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data

> fibers@1.0.5 install /tmp/build_3881053bffeea07424230758a68b5e92/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers

> node ./build.js

`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing

Binary is fine; exiting

ansi-regex@0.2.1 node_modules/ansi-regex

ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles

escape-string-regexp@1.0.3 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap

underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

meteor-promise@0.5.0 node_modules/meteor-promise

promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise

source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers

-----> Adding PATH environment

-----> Running extras

-----> Adding MONGOHQ_URL -> MONGO_URL env

-----> Adding MONGOLAB_URI -> MONGO_URL env

-----> Installing phantomjs.

-----> Discovering process types

   Procfile declares types     -> (none)

   Default types for buildpack -> web

-----> Compressing...

   Done: 30.1M

-----> Launching...

   Released v15

   https://<appname>.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

best

M

Comment: how did you install the packages and if they are local how are you pointing to them? local packages need to be referenced in your projects `packages/` folder. How are you deploying to heroku?

Comment: answered your questions in the edit - How do I reference them? because in the project folder there is a textfile ./meteor/packages with all the package names - the source code is in $HOME/.meteor/packages/<package>

Comment: ok looks good so far. I suspect you just didn't commit your `.meteor` folder in your project? Among other things it contains `packages` and `versions` which tell the deployment what needs to be installed. Also, I'm not an expert in heroku, but I would imagine that you should use `meteor build` to deploy. How are you currently executing the app on heroku? Does it run `meteor`?

Comment: the .meteor folder is different in the proecte folder than the $home/.meteor folder wich contains the source files - the "packages" file in the proect folder just contains a list with all installed packages (including the new ones) - through git push heroku master, I assume the application gets build automatically - on the localhost I start the server through meteor run

Comment: yes, I know. And the versions file contains the exact versions of the desired packages (to complement the names). But did you add these text files to your git, i.e. are you pushing them to heroku?

Comment: yes I do, added the build-log